# How to create a count table of two variables in excel pivot

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

Is it ok to cross post this question?

I am struggling with creating a count table of two variables at the same time. Ultimately, I would like to create a bar graph of the table.

Assuming I have two items for a sample of firms and I just want a summary table of the answer count.

```
Firm       Item1    Item2
1          1        1
2          2        1
3          1        2
4          1        2
```

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076802/how-to-create-a-bar-graph-in-excel-2010-by-counts), I can easily create the summary table for Item 1 telling me that "1" appears three times for item 1 and two times in Item 2. But I cant easily create a Pivot table showing this jointly.

To clarify what I would like I added two screenshots (Excel unfortunately in German)
[image]

This is where it does not work, because he uses the values of Item 1 to count for item 2.

One solution would be to go long, but I would not know an easy way to do this in Excel for a more elaborate data set.

[image]

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by jointly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proposed solution is the right way to follow.

You have to "unpivot" your Inputs in this tabular form in order to use the Excel pivot function efficiently.

```
company | variable | value.
```

If you got your raw data in the first form

```
company | value variable 1 | value variable 2 | value variable 3 | ....
```

then the best (and probably easiest) way is to transform / unpivot the raw inputs using the Power Query functionality of Excel ([Get & Transform](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-Transform-in-Excel-2016-881c63c6-37c5-4ca2-b616-59e18d75b4de), up to Excel 2013 as Addin [Power Query](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=39379)).

Follow these steps:

- Import your data in Power Query (define your Inputs as table)
  Go to Data > Get & Transform > From Table (Excel 2016) or Power Query > Excel Data > From Table (Excel 2013 & 2010)
- select the column company  (or if you have more which you want to Keep)
- on the transform tab, right click on unpivot column. Choose the Option unpivot other columns
- Click Close & Load from the Home tab

Here the M-Code which will be generated by the UI

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabelle1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Company", Int64.Type}, {"1", type text}, {"2", type text}, {"3", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Company"}, "Attribut", "Wert")
in
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns"
```

You can also follow a good tutorial [here](https://trumpexcel.com/unpivot-data/).

Comment: Ok so going Long is the way to go. If needed I can easily do this in R or eventually I will wait for the upgrade to Excel 2016 that should come eventually. I am afraid that my IT will block installing the above mentioned addins. I can mark your answer as the answer if there is really no other way

Comment: since this addin (for Excel 2010 and Excel 2012) is delivered by Microsoft himself, I think you should be able to convince your IT. One argument more: they integrated Power Query in Excel 2016 now.

Comment: You dont know my IT... goverment etc.