# Excel Pivot Table - Change Columns using Filter

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, column

I have a pivot table and values separated by a signal flag (0 or 1). I many different signal types (columns) to use.

[image: Example of Two Pivot Tables, each using one signal column]

**Question:** Instead of creating a new pivot table for each signal, is there a 'column filter' I can add to quickly change the first pivot table to the second as in the picture?

I can't add the signals as a filter as I need all the data to be used.

Comment: As far as I know, any of pivot areas (filters, columns, rows) all work on row data. Each "Signal" column is a field on its own and there is no fields of fields or selector/filter of fields. One way to do this would be to "flatten" your data. Reshape it all into a single column with an extra helper column called signal, and signal number listed there in,

Comment: Perhaps post a screenshot of your original data too.

Comment: What is the original columns names and what data they contain? Can you please share some example?

Comment: Data is four columns: Team color (B or R), Count (all 1's), and Signal 1 or 2 (randomly assigns a row 0 or 1).

Answer (score 0):

you have to rearrange your input table like this

| Team color | Count | Signal Type (1 or 2) | Signal Value |

Then you can slice on the column Signal Type.

s. the concept in [this older answer](https://superuser.com/a/1334602/583258).